# Azure APIM pass through request querystring to backend completely

Tags: azure-api-management

On Azure APIM I have an operation that has querystring parameters.
In the policy I change the backend url and apply a rewrite-uri to alter the url.
Only the querystring from the caller is not applied to the backend.

Is it possible to passthrough the incoming querystring directly to the backend without changing anything?

```
<inbound>
    <base />
    <set-backend-service base-url="https://api.test.eu" />
    <rewrite-uri template="dispatch/gateway/test" />
</inbound>
```

**UPDATE**

Fixed by using the folloing:

```
<set-backend-service base-url="https://api.test.eu" />
<rewrite-uri template="/dispatch/gateway/test" copy-unmatched-params="true" />
```

Comment: The query parameters passthrough is the default behaviour unless you explicitly remove them.

Comment: I have been stuck on something similar for a day now, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm having variable(id) in api request url which will be passed with interface uri

request url - **[https://hostname.com/apiname/v1/Tasks(guid'(ID)')](https://hostname.com/apiname/v1/Tasks(guid%27(ID)%27))**

```
<rewrite-uri template="/Projects(guid'(ID)')/Tasks" copy-unmatched-params="true" />
```

as ID is variable, final action id value should be same as request url ID. how to pass variable in rewrite uri.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure how this answers the question. Can you clarify?